# What type of axios error i need for getting error.response.data.status?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

```
(e: AxiosError) => console.log(e.response?.data.status)
```

Here i have an error (Object is of type 'unknown'). But server give me response like

```
{status: 'error description'}
```

With "any" of course it work perfect. But it's not a solution. How can i use typescript at this situation?

Comment: Try `e.response.status`

Comment: its another status. 
`e.response?.status` just error code. But i need to get special status, response from server.

Comment: The message do you want? what is the special status? for the message use `e.response.data.exceptionMessage`

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/_dWA5CtYgpoj) this is response from server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AxiosError` has generic parameter to type:

```js
export interface AxiosError<T = any> extends Error {
  config: AxiosRequestConfig;
  code?: string;
  request?: any;
  response?: AxiosResponse<T>;
  isAxiosError: boolean;
  toJSON: () => object;
}
```

And it's `any` by default. You just need to specify type of `T`:

```js
(e: AxiosError<{ status: string }>) => 
     console.log(e.response?.data.status)
```